# Navigation component fragment does not back to previous fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have 2 fragments, `A` and `B` and whenever fragment A starts I check a condition and send user to fragment B:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    fetchData()
}
private fun fetchData(){
    prefs = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(UtilConstraints.sharePrefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    nightMode=prefs.getBoolean(UtilConstraints.sharedPrefsNightMode,false)
    fMainNightModeSwitch.isChecked=nightMode

    if(!prefs.contains(UtilConstraints.sharedPrefsMyLang)){
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_selectLangFragment)
    }
}
```

and in fragment B I return to previous one with a button click:

```
    fSelectLangSaveSettings.setOnClickListener{
        if(otherLangs.size<3){
            Snackbar.make(
                fSelectLangContainer,
                "You Must Select Your Favorite Languages",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }else {
            prefs.edit().clear().putString(UtilConstraints.sharedPrefsMyLang, currentLang).apply()
            Snackbar.make(
                fSelectLangContainer,
                "Languages Saved Successfully",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            findNavController().navigateUp()
        }
    }
```

Also here is my `nav_graph`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/selectLangFragment"
    android:name="com.trinitytech.qtranslate.fragments.SelectLangFragment"
    android:label="fragment_select_lang"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_select_lang" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_selectLangFragment_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment"/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.trinitytech.qtranslate.fragments.MainFragment"
    android:label="MainFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_selectLangFragment"
        app:destination="@id/selectLangFragment" />
</fragment>
```

The thing is this problem only occurs when I try to automatically navigate to fragment B and it works fine when I use a button click to navigate to B.

I also tried other solutions in stackoverflow but none of them work for me.

Comment: Have u tried popBackStack() instead navigateUp()?

Comment: @P.Juni yes and unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Does it work if you set the PoptoInclusive to false?

Comment: @AdityaKurkure that also didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatically navigate to fragment B'? It sounds like you're going back to the previous destination just fine, but then immediately triggering that same logic again. Can you include some more code surrounding your automatic navigation' and confirm that your `navigate()` call is happening again and again?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I can not navigate back from second fragment, that is my current problem. Im pretty sure its not a loop but please let me edit my question.

Comment: i believe u should change app:popUpTo="@+id/mainFragment" to app:popUpTo="@+id/selectLangFragment" and set popBackStck() Check if this works

Comment: @P.Juni tnx I'll test it

Comment: Did you try using `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_selectLangFragment_to_mainFragment`) in your select lang fragment?

Comment: So is your `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_selectLangFragment)` call being called multiple times? What does `navigateUp()` return?

Answer (score 0):

> @ianhanniballake I can not navigate back from second fragment, that is my current problem. Im pretty sure its not a loop but please let me edit my question. –

As i conclude from your comment is that whenever you try to go back from fragment B you can't go back, but that's not the case actually your fragment B navigate back to fragment A and whenever you go back to fragment A from fragment B `onViewCreated` is called then your `fetchData()` method is also called and your logic remains same so it's again navigate to fragment B. You can either change your logic or atleast invoke `fetchData()` in some button listener.

Comment: thanks. the problem wasn't from that part. I was able to handle the problem creating a custom navhost component and linking these two fragment

Comment: @ianhanniballake yeas I'm also sure its not a good way to do it, since I have a little more time I'm trying to find a more reliable way to handle it.